# Remote_Host index not showing

Tags: php, html, apache, apache2

We are running suse11 apache2.2 server.
When we try to get REMOTE_HOST we get an error "index not found" as shown below

```
REMOTE_HOST : Notice: Undefined index: REMOTE_HOST in /media/nss/VOL1/htdocs/serverVars.php on line 44 

HTTP_REFERER : Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in /media/nss/VOL1/htdocs/serverVars.php on line 45 

REMOTE_USER : Notice: Undefined index: REMOTE_USER in /media/nss/VOL1/htdocs/serverVars.php on line 46
```

Here is a sample of what we are using to troubleshoot the problem.

```
<?php 
    print " BCIS serverVars.php " . "<br />";
    print "DOCUMENT_ROOT : ";   print  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "<br />";
    print "SERVER_NAME   : ";   print $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "<br />";
    print "HTTP_HOST     : ";   print $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "<br />";
    print "HTTP_COOKIE     : "; print $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] . "<br />";

    print "----------------------------------------- <br />";

    print "REMOTE_HOST   : ";   print $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] . "<br />";
    print "HTTP_REFERER  : ";   print $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "<br />";
    print "REMOTE_USER   : ";   print $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] . "<br />";
    print "PATH_INFO     : ";   print $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] . "<br />";
?>
```

Could someone direct us on the correct path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See the manual on [`$_SERVER["REMOTE_HOST"]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> Note: Your web server must be configured to create this variable. For example in Apache you'll need `HostnameLookups On` inside httpd.conf for it to exist. See also [gethostbyaddr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php).

Note that turning `HostnameLookups On` can be bad for performance, as DNS lookups can be resource expensive. See [the Apache documentation on `HostnameLookups`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#hostnamelookups) for details.

Comment: I have placed "HostNameLookups On" in both httpd.conf and when that did not solve the problem I placed it in my vhost config file. Still did not work. When I first opened the httpd.conf file "HostnameLookups" did not exist. So I added it at the bottom of the file. Is this the right place? Is there somthing more that I need to enable?

Answer (score 0):

According to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> "Your web server must be configured to create this variable. For example in Apache you'll need HostnameLookups On inside httpd.conf for it to exist."